# Getting jshint to play nice with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

in my main app.js, I define my app:

```
var app = angular.module('ccApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);
```

In my various controller files, I define controllers:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $log, $location, $rootScope, $window) {...
```

These lines are all flagged as errors with jshint as "app not defined".  The app works fine; when the scripts are all concatenated they see the variable definition.

How do I get jshint to "understand" this and not flag this as an error?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: you just need to read jshint documentation. http://jshint.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

If `app` is global, you can predefine variables (so jshint knows they exist) in your configuration (whether it's via a `.jshintrc` file or some other method:

```
{
  "predef": ["app"]
}
```

You can also do it on a per-file basis with jshint's inline configuration by adding this comment directive to the top of your files:

```
/* global app */
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
var app = angular.module('ccApp', ...
```

you should be using

```
// in app.js once with dependencies
angular.module('ccApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute')

// in component files
angular.module('ccApp')
    .controller('..', ...
```

that should take care of your jshint. also if you'd plan on re-using your app as a library, you'd have problems with, since you already use the global variable (`var app`) or others might use it without knowing and run into problems.

Comment: I used to do that, but a senior co-worker said to do it the other way...  Oy.

Comment: it is the recommended way of doing it. also as mentioned, it takes care of polluting the global variable space.

Comment: I think the idea is to make the files able to be dropped into any app that has a main module "app"

Comment: you develop for a specific app or library, not just any app. you really shouldn't use the global variable way of declaring modules.